# Void Value Not Ignored As It Ought To Be

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm a rookie with c++ and OOP in general.. and well.. here's my code:

Classes: http://3.ii.gl/QxZvWqK5h.png

Main & Functions: http://3.ii.gl/jawvqCtbH.png

The error message "void ought to be ignored" .. seems like the compiler is thinking that I am trying to return a value for my SetName(string strName) .. but it clearly doesn't return a value, it is only supposed to change the private variable. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please include the code in the question.

Comment: Why is your code in png files? If you want it online use something like ideone.com. But should really be in the question as well. And in ideone.com for easy checking.

Comment: If your editor doesn't support copying the text, it's time that you upgrade to something more advanced, like Notepad.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*pcPlayer->SetName(strName);
```

`SetName()` returns `void`, which you're trying to dereference with the `*`. Just drop the `*`.

If you want to access a pointer-to-pointer's pointee's pointee's members (phew), the syntax is :

```
(*pptr)->member;
```

Comment: Yep, `->` and `.` have higher precedence than unary `*`... And we used to call those pointer-to-pointer things "handles" on the ancient Macs.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone what about pointers-to-pointers-to-pointers ? ;)

Comment: Pointers to handles. Haven't seen anything crazier than that.

Comment: ahh.. pointers so tricky. i should have realized this lol. Thank you